# Como definir propriedades condicionais para um objeto literal da maneira mais enxuta possível com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Gostaria de saber como adicionar propriedades condicionais em um objeto literal da maneira mais enxuta possível.

Atualmente declaro o objeto e depois adiciono as propriedades condicionais como no exemplo a seguir:

```
function getFamilia(avos) {
  const familia = {
    filhos: ['Pedro', 'Claudia'],
    pais: ['Marcio', 'Fernanda']
  }

  if (avos) {
     familia.avos = avos
  }

  return familia
}
```

Já tentei fazer um ternário na definição do objeto mas a chave continua lá mesmo que retorne undefined. Exemplo:

```
const getFamilia = avos => ({
  filhos: ['Pedro', 'Claudia'],
  pais: ['Marcio', 'Fernanda'],
  avos: avos || undefined
})
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer condicionais diretamente na declaração do objeto sem deixar a chave lá no caso falso?

Pode usar qualquer recurso de qualquer versão do javascript.

Comment: Não consigo entender de jeito algum, hum... O que você quer é que a propriedade `'avos'` não exista?

Comment: Exato @Matheus. Caso ela tenha um valor queria que o objeto tivesse a propriedade preenchida. Caso não tenha, queria que ela nem existisse no objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua criação de objeto esta com uma definição errada. O que você esta fazendo é uma função que retorna um objeto e não uma classe no javascript.
Com uma classe você consegue garantir que o atributo existira pois ele esta definido nela.

```js
/*
 *  JS Class
 *
  function Familia(filhos, pais, avos) {
    if(filhos) this.filhos = filhos;
    if(pais) this.pais = pais;
    if(avos) this.avos = avos;
  }
/*
 */
 
/*
 *  ES6 Class
 */
class Familia {
  constructor(filhos, pais, avos) {
    if(filhos) this.filhos = filhos;
    if(pais) this.pais = pais;
    if(avos) this.avos = avos;
  }
}
/*
 */
 

let familiaCompleta = new Familia(['Pedro', 'Claudia'], ['Marcio', 'Fernanda'], ['Frank']);
console.log(familiaCompleta);

let semFilhos = new Familia(null, ['Marcio', 'Fernanda'], ['Frank']);
console.log(semFilhos);

let semPais = new Familia(['Pedro', 'Claudia'], null, ['Frank']);
console.log(semPais);

let semAvos = new Familia(['Pedro', 'Claudia'], ['Marcio', 'Fernanda'], null);
console.log(semAvos);
```

Comment: não resolveu o problema. Criou o objeto com a propriedade avos igual a `null` além de ter sido extremamente mais verboso que as demais soluções.

Comment: E só para constar, você não precisa de uma classe para criar objetos em javascript.

As duas funções do exemplo retornam um objeto. A diferença é que não são a instância de uma classe, mas continuam sendo objetos.

Comment: Voce pode colocar os valores default como mostrado no comentario:
this.filhos = filhos || [];
Apesar de ser mais "verboso" ele retorna uma classe verdadeira permitindo que voce tenha melhor uso de POO.

Comment: Mas se voce for ver a classe em ES6 exigi mais linhas para digitar, mesmo assim voce pode optar pela classe vanilla, que esta comentada, que fica menor que o seu exemplo apresentado na pergunta.

Comment: fugiu do escopo da pergunta. Quero que o objeto só possua a propriedade avos caso o parâmetro avos exista. Caso contrário gostaria que o objeto nem tivesse a propriedade.

Comment: Eu havia entendido que voce queria uma forma de tratar o valor de uma propriedade de uma classe em poucas linhas, nao que voce fosse remover a propriedade.

Comment: Não é para remover. É para adicionar de forma condicional. Se tem adiciona, se não tem não adiciona. Não gostaria de ter a propriedade avos igual a `null` ou `undefined`. Gostaria que ela nem existisse na definição do objeto caso não exista.

Comment: Nesse caso estou fazendo a alteracao

Comment: Pronto, essa é a forma mais limpa possivel. Apesar de que se voce pensar em orientacao a objetos, conceitualmente  isso nao é algo correto de se fazer (apenas pesando sobre a questao de integridade dos objetos)

Comment: Ainda é muito verboso, mas aparentemente é a forma mais enxuta.

Answer (score 0):

É possível resolver a ação de definir dessa propriedade (reconhecida como [[PUT]] pelas especificações do ECMAScript, ou "set"), ou a leitura ([[GET]], ou "get") no objeto. Isso é apenas diretamente disponível no ECMAScript 5 e acima (principalmente no ECMAScript 6).

Criando um `Proxy` você pode controlar todas ações de [[PUT]] de uma vez (parece muito com as meta(tables do Lua)) no mesmo objeto.

```
const meta = {
    set: (f, prop, value) => {
        // Toda propriedade deve conter um objeto.
        if (value instanceof Object) {
            f[prop] = value
            return true
        }
        // Não redefine a propriedade nesse caso.
        return false
    }
}

const getFamilia = avos => {
    var init = {
        filhos: ['Pedro', 'Claudia'],
        pais: ['Marcio', 'Fernanda']
    }
    var f = new Proxy(init, meta)
    f.avos = avos
    return f
}
```

[O `Proxy` vem do ES6.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxy-objects)